# Regular expression that don't match 0

Tags: regex

I want to test with regex if a string does not match "0"

`"a"`, `"00"`, `"0a"`, `"a0"` are valid strings.
`"0"` is not

my actual regex is

```
^(0.+|[^0].*)$
```

Is there a easier way (regex) to deal with this kind of situations.

Comment: So the only string you don't want is "0" ?

Comment: Can't you use `notEquals("0")` instead (pseudocode)?

Comment: MisterJ Yes.
sp00m No, only regex

Comment: Looks like a neat regex to me

Comment: I think that it is too long to do an easy stuff like excluding "0" string

Comment: @Ghilas: I wouldn't worry too much about it. If regex is your only option just put a comment above it explaining what it does (disallow the string "0") and be done with it. I'd say it's unlikely to ever become a performance or maintenance problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming whatever regex system you are using supports the negative lookahead operator `?!`, you could do

```
^(?!0$)
```

which matches all strings (including the empty string) except `"0"`

Comment: What are you using to evaluate it?  I run `php -r 'var_dump(preg_match("/^(?!0$)/", $argv[1]));' 00` and get `int(1)`